# How to Reboot Programmatically?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How can I reboot in c++? Is there any provision in WinSDK? What kind of rights should my program(process) have to do so?

Comment: I don't suggest that you do this. The user would probably hate it if the system reboots without them doing it themselves.

Comment: I will ask the user before I do so(save your stuff blah, blah..)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is the [ExitWindowsEx Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868%28VS.85%29.aspx) that can do this. You need to pass the **EWX_REBOOT** (0x00000002) flag to restart the system.

Important note here (quote from **MSDN**):

> The **ExitWindowsEx** function returns as soon as it has initiated the shutdown process. The shutdown or logoff then proceeds asynchronously. The function is designed to stop all processes in the caller's logon session. Therefore, if you are not the interactive user, the function can succeed without actually shutting down the computer. If you are not the interactive user, use the **InitiateSystemShutdown** or **InitiateSystemShutdownEx** function.

You can choose between the appropriate function depending on your situation.

Answer (score 9):

Before calling the [ExitWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868%28VS.85%29.aspx) function you need to [enable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446619(v=VS.85).aspx) the [SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530716(v=VS.85).aspx):

1. OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess (),TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,...)
2. LookupPrivilegeValue
3. AdjustTokenPrivileges
4. CloseHandle

Answer (score 5):

I presume you have a very good case for wanting to reboot a PC that may be running lots of other applications.

It sounds like you are looking for [`InitiateShutdown()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376872(VS.85).aspx), passing `SHUTDOWN_RESTART` in `dwShutdownFlags`.

Answer (score 1):

@Anders solution would look, Not sure if this is fully functional as I wrote this a while ago and have not run it in a while. Documentation below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-adjusttokenprivileges

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupprivilegevaluea

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdowna

```
void shutSystemOff(const bool &shutReboot = true)
{
    // Create all required variables
    int vRet = 0;
    bool adjustRet;
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;
    LUID luid;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;

    // Get LUID for current boot for current process.
    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, &luid);

    // Modify and Adjust token privileges for current process.
    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    adjustRet = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, false, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, 0);

    // Check if token privileges were set.
    if (adjustRet)
    {
        // Initiates system shutdown ( Local system, Shutdown Message, Dwell time, Prompt user, Reboot )
        InitiateSystemShutdownA(NULL, NULL, 0, true, shutReboot);
    }
}
```